# ARKit - Placing objects in front of camera in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

When I use the transform from the current ARFrame to place an object in front of the camera, it seems to use landscape as the orientation of the device. Therefore if I hold the device in portrait and place an object it will appear tilted 90 degrees.

I would like the orientation of the object to be placed relative to portrait of the device instead. Is it possible to change this? Or do I have to rotate the anchor? And how would one do that?

Here is how I am creating the anchor:

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else  { return }

    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translation.columns.3.z = -1

    let transform = currentFrame.camera.transform
    let anchorTransform = matrix_multiply(transform, translation)

    var anchor = ARAnchor(transform: anchorTransform)
    self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

And below is how I am creating the node for rendering. Note that I have two child nodes in one parent node as I would like to be able to move these two nodes around as one.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let childOne = SCNNode()
    childOne.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.1, length: 0.3, chamferRadius: 0)
    childOne.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

    let childTwo = SCNNode()
    childTwo.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.5, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    childTwo.position = SCNVector3(0, 0.25, 0)
    childTwo.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

    let node = SCNNode()
    node.addChildNode(nodeOne)
    node.addChildNode(nodeTwo)

    return node
}
```

**Update**

Solved it by creating a rotation matrix for rotating Z-axis 90 degrees and then multiplied it with the translation matrix.

```
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else  { return }

    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translation.columns.3.z = -1

    let transform = currentFrame.camera.transform

    let rotation = matrix_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float.pi/2, 0, 0, 1))

    let anchorTransform = matrix_multiply(transform, matrix_multiply(translation, rotation))

    var anchor = ARAnchor(transform: anchorTransform)
    self.sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to place the object in front of the camera?

Comment: @JoshRobbins yes, just to place it one meter in front of the camera, which works fine when the device is in landscape, but the orientation of the object is wrong when I am placing it while holding the device in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

Portrait-vs-landscape seems to work automatically if you get the camera matrix via [pointOfView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview)

```
    let anchorTransform = pointOfView!.convertTransform(SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -1),  to: nil)
```